# How to use Bash rename to prepend a hyphen?

Tags: bash, rename

I want some files that end with `.png` to end with `-sm.png`.

I tried with `rename .png -sm.png *.png` but it failed with `invalid option -- 'm'`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this method

```
rename 's/.png/-sm.png/' *
```

Comment: Are you using Linux or other?